# statsmodel sm implementation - calculation of SEs

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to figure out how the standard errors are calculated by statsmodels.sm.api:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("Advertising.csv", index_col=0)
X = sm.add_constant(data[['TV', 'radio' ,'newspaper']])
y = data["sales"]
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
y_hat = np.dot(X, model.params)
residuals = y - y_hat
var = (np.sum(residuals**2))/(200-3-1)
```

And as I understand this equation give me standard error matrix, where diagonal are standard errors for each parameter:

```
np.sqrt(var * (np.dot(X.T, X)**-1))

array([[0.11918358, 0.00982868, 0.02471008, 0.02156167],
   [0.00982868, 0.00070041, 0.00201736, 0.00175762],
   [0.02471008, 0.00201736, 0.00432171, 0.00415011],
   [0.02156167, 0.00175762, 0.00415011, 0.0031791 ]])
```

But according to the model.summary standard error differ from the above:

```
"""
                            OLS Regression Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  sales   R-squared:                       0.897
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.896
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     570.3
Date:                Sun, 10 Nov 2019   Prob (F-statistic):           1.58e-96
Time:                        08:29:40   Log-Likelihood:                -386.18
No. Observations:                 200   AIC:                             780.4
Df Residuals:                     196   BIC:                             793.6
Df Model:                           3
Covariance Type:            nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          2.9389      0.312      9.422      0.000       2.324       3.554
TV             0.0458      0.001     32.809      0.000       0.043       0.049
radio          0.1885      0.009     21.893      0.000       0.172       0.206
newspaper     -0.0010      0.006     -0.177      0.860      -0.013       0.011
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       60.414   Durbin-Watson:                   2.084
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              151.241
Skew:                          -1.327   Prob(JB):                     1.44e-33
Kurtosis:                       6.332   Cond. No.                         454.
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
"""
```

How are those SEs calculated?

Comment: `xtx**(-1)` is elementwise inverse in numpy. try `np.linalg.inv(xtx)` for matrix inverse

Comment: @Josef You are right. Please put it as an answer and I will flag it as this if you wish so. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation looks correct, however operations on numpy arrays are mostly elementwise.

If `xtx = X.T.dot(X)`, then `xtx**(-1)` is elementwise inverse in numpy. We need to use the `linalg` functions in numpy or scipy for the matrix inverse, i.e. `np.linalg.inv(xtx)`.

The computation in OLS in statsmodels differs from this in that a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse, `pinv`, based on a SVD decomposition is used by default, or optionally the computation are based on a QR decomposition.

Both decomposition are applied to the design matrix, `exog`, which has better numerical precision than using the matrix inverse of the moment matrix `inv(xtx)`. However, the former is usually slower than the latter, trading off speed for precision.